# Is there single sign in solution for JDBC in an application server?

Tags: java, jdbc, single-sign-on, application-server

I want to login to a database with the account of the current user. Is there a solution to forward the account information to a JDBC connection in an application server?

Comment: Which database is this? AFAIK there is no generic solution. Most solutions rely on the underlying database server to support this. For instance, Oracle supports this via it's proxy-authentication feature.

Comment: Most people would prefer database accounts to have no direct relation to application user accounts...

Comment: look for single-sing-on (based on LDAP, AD ...)

Comment: @Mikaveli then you can not use the security features of the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the username/password to DataSource#getConnection(String username, String password).

Whether or not you use Spring for your data layer you can utilize the UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter class to allow you to set the current username/password in the current thread.  So for example:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myRealDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MyDataSource"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter">
  <property name="targetDataSource" ref="myRealDataSource"/>
  <property name="username">${default.username}</property>
  <property name="password">${default.password}</property>
</bean>
```

In your code where you have access to the username/password (perhaps inside of a Servlet Filter) you could set the username and password for the current thread, and then clear it afterwards.  Your Filter would have a reference to the UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter data source with UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter as the type.  So your DAO would be wired with the data source type DataSource, while the filter uses the same object using its more specific type.  This is to allow the filter to do the following:

```
private UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter userCredentialsDataSourceAdapter
void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
              ServletResponse response,
              FilterChain chain)
              throws IOException,
                     ServletException {

  String username, password; // retrieve from the request or cache
  userCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.setCredentialsForCurrentThread(username, password);

  try {
    chain.doFilter();
  } finally {
    userCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.removeCredentialsFromCurrentThread();
  }
}
```

What this does is while the credentials are current, getConnection() will delegate to getConnection(String, String) with the specified credentials.  Your data layer really won't know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void connectToAndQueryDatabase(String username, String password) {

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:myDriver:myDatabase", username, password);

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM Table1");
while (rs.next()) {
    int x = rs.getInt("a");
    String s = rs.getString("b");
    float f = rs.getFloat("c");
}
// ...
```

I guess you knew that setting up a connection to the DB typically involves passing a username and password. So at any given time you have the possibility to 'forward' the account info, as you've put it. Does 'an application server' have a ready-built solution for this? Who knows? We don't even know what app-server you're using ..

Your question is probably not answered yet because you are leaving out plenty of details of what it is you're trying to achieve and in which situation (technologies, ..) you're looking for a solution.

You talk about using the database's security features but not what in particular you're trying to accomplish. Probably there are other ways than using user accounts (roles etc).

And typically a 'single-sign-on' solution involves a separate mechanism to control the accounts and rights and so on. Choosing one is again influenced by what other systems (app-server, db, ..) you're planning to use.

- [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649350.aspx)
- [oracle article](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97329_03/core.902/a90146/features.htm)
- [softwaremag.com article](http://www.softwaremag.com/focus-areas/security/featured-articles/authentication-and-authorization-are-app-dev-pain-points/)
- ...

Look for articles about securing web applications (provided that's what you're developing), authentication and authorisation. (The above links might be outdated but still hold valuable info.)

And definitely take security serious.

Cheers,
Wim

(Wanted to comment but it turned out a larger comment than expected)

Comment: My can also revers my question. I want login to an application server with an database account and receive a connection for this account. You sample does not described how I can receive the password. That it must be a solution to create a database connection without a password with the current login.

Comment: You definitely should read some articles and books etc concerning authentication and authorisation. The ones that I've listed should get you some deeper understanding on these security issues and help you design the security for the application you're making. I'm no guru myself but I know that securing applications is a job on its own and shouldn't be thought of as "I'll implement this little piece of code or that library and I'm good to go".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jersey rest you can also use one of the filters:

```
public class PoweredByResponseFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
        throws IOException {

        final SecurityContext securityContext =
                containerRequestContext.getSecurityContext();
        if (securityContext != null) {
            // Dummy values
            userCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.setUsername("test");
            userCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.setPassword("test");
        }
    }
}
```

And when you are in the response, remove it again:

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
    userCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.removeCredentialsFromCurrentThread();
}
```